# Solving this question using ln?

Tags: calculus, logarithms

I know that ln is used to bring down exponents usually, so I was wondering where would I go from there ? I've looked at symbolab and don't really understand the implicit differentiation approach.

Here's the question $e^{(x^2)y}=2x+2y$

I was able to get to:

$$x^2y \ln(e) = \ln(2x)+ \ln(2y)$$

Where would i go from here ?

Comment: The logarithm of a sum is not generally equal to the sum of the logarithms of the summands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to point out that you have made a common mistake. You seem to believe (correct me if I'm wrong) that
$$\ln(a+b)=\ln a+\ln b$$
This is *wrong*. In actual fact, the log law that you may be confusing this with is:

$$\ln(ab)=\ln a+\ln b$$
Note: this log law is not unique to the natural logarithm, it is a property of all logarithms.

About your question, your equation has infinitely many solutions. I assume that you want to differentiate it implicitly (as opposed to solving it), so this is how you'd do it. It is inconvenient in this case to use $\ln$ as we don't have a product on the right hand side of our original equation, so I will differentiate directly:

$$e^{x^2y}=2x+2y$$
Now, differentiating with respect to $x$, and using the fact that $\frac{d}{dx}e^{f(x)}=f'(x)e^{f(x)}$ we have
$$\begin{align}
&\frac{d}{dx}(e^{x^2y})=\frac{d}{dx}(2x)+\frac{d}{dx}(2y)\\
&\left(2xy+x^2\frac{dy}{dx}\right)e^{x^2y}=2+2\frac{dy}{dx}
\end{align}$$
Now rearrange to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$. If you need any more help please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: So for the left side, 2xy comes from taking the derivative of x^2y, and then we keep the f`(x) because we are doing implicit correct?

Comment: @curiousJoe basically, yes! Just to clarify: Differentiating $x^2y$ with respect to $x$ can be done using implicit differentiation and the product rule, as follows: The derivative is equal to $$y\frac{d}{dx}(x^2)+x^2\frac{d}{dx}(y)$$ which is $$2xy+x^2\frac{dy}{dx}$$

Comment: Cool! I'm at this point in the equation and I believe im on the right track.

Comment: dy/dx(x^2-2) = 2-2xy/(e^xy)

Comment: @curiousJoe not quite- remember that the bit in the large brackets in the final line of my answer is also multiplied by $e^{x^2y}$. If you need any more help I can help you tomorrow (I'm going to bed now).